# Laravel 3.x Route issue: page not found even with the route set

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-3

I got an annoying problem with a route, for a section of a CMS that I'm developing.
I got routes for all the sections, "products", for example:

```
    Route::get('admin/products', array('as' => 'admin/products', 'uses'=> 'admin.products@index'));
    Route::get('admin/products/create', array('as' => 'admin/products/create', 'uses'=> 'admin.products@create'));
    Route::get('admin/products/edit/(:num)', array('as' => 'admin/products/edit', 'uses'=> 'admin.products@edit'));
    Route::get('admin/products/delete/(:num)', array('as' => 'admin/products/delete', 'uses'=> 'admin.products@delete'));
```

.. and the related files, like the products controller, the product model and the views.

Everything was doing well until I decided to create a new section, "users". I used the same approach as "products", creating the routes and the other files. In fact I just copied and paste the files, making the changes when needed -- pretty straightforward. By accessing "admin/users" and "admin/users/create", it works as expected. But I can't access "/users/edit/1" and "/users/delete/1". I thought it would be a route problem, but when I tested the route file, I got a 404 even before reaching the route. Here's an example:

```
    Route::get('admin/users/edit/(:num)', function()
    {
        return "Holy Hell.";
    });
```

"Holy Hell" is never printed into the screen.

Here's the config for "users":

```
    Route::get('admin/users', array('as' => 'admin/users', 'uses'=> 'admin.users@index'));
    Route::get('admin/users/edit/(:num)', array('as' => 'admin/users/edit/', 'uses'=> 'admin.users@edit'));
    Route::get('admin/users/create', array('as' => 'admin/users/create', 'uses'=> 'admin.users@create'));
    Route::get('admin/users/delete/(:num)', array('as' => 'admin/users/delete', 'uses'=> 'admin.users@delete'));
```

***Things that I noticed / Checked:***

- The index view, where is the users list, got a "URL::to_route('admin/users/edit')" function. I have no errors on the screen, so Laravel understands that the route 'admin/users/edit' is set correctly.
- I know that this is not a general problem, because the "edit" and "delete" methods for the other CMS sections have no issues.
- The views for these methods are there. So this is not a "file not found" issue.

I wonder if I'm missing something really obvious here. Any ideas? If not, would anyone please tell me how to debug this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT: Heads up

Your routes are in a bad order. Reverse them. Routes are evaluated top down, so anything with `admin/products` in the route will route to `admin.products@index` and nothing else.

In your `edit` method, you need to have the `id` parameter defined.

Since you didn't post your controller, I'm assuming this is why, since the closure does not have the `$id` passed to it. Example:

```
// Required user id:
Route::get('admin/users/edit/(:num)', function($id)
{
  return "Holy Hell.";
});

// Optional user id:
Route::get('admin/users/edit/(:num?)', function($id = null)
{
  return "Holy Hell.";
});
```

In your case, you probably don't want the optional part unless you plan on spewing out an error (or redirecting on error).

Comment: I don't think this is it, the route should still run the Closure just no parameter will be passed. It's a good suggestion but I'm doubtful it will resolve OP problem. **Edit** but yeh, you're right about the route ordering

Comment: @Rob W Thanks. I followed your sugestion and changed the order I declared the routes. Everything is fine now.